# Xcode 6 on Yosemite: Give me back my title bar!

Tags: macos, xcode

On prior versions of OS X and Xcode I constantly used the title bar right-click to view the folder hierarchy of the Xcode project: right-click the title bar and open up the containing folder (or an ancestor).

However now that Xcode has no title bar I can't do this anymore. Is there any way to bring back the title bar so I can open the containing folder quickly and easily again?

I know I can right-click the project icon in the project navigator pane and choose "Show in Finder", but this is much less convenient as it requires that pane be visible, and it only opens the direct containing folder, not any ancestor I want (nor can I use it to quickly verify the project is the one I think it is). Thankfully the Finder windows still have a title bar so I can do it then, but it's still at least a couple steps extra for something that used to be a single-click operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could right click on the top bar and open the folders you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try command clicking on the blue Project folder, for you it's the Portfolio Manager App bit on the left.